# Magento - Using alternative "reviews count" on category list page

Tags: magento

I noticed that on the category list page, the number of reviews (pulled from **frontend/base/default/template/review/helper/summary_short.phtml**) lists the full amount of reviews for an item, not the amount available to the store view you’re on.

So, for example (using the sample data) the Samsung MM-A900M Ace has 5 reviews - however, when you click that link and are taken to the reviews page, it actually just has 2 (as only 2 are available to the English view). But on the reviews page, the review count is correct and says 2 reviews (this time pulled from **frontend/base/default/template/review/product/view/count.phtml**).

Is there any way to use this review count on the category list?